# Change url via JavaScript (no hash-tag)

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, hash

I'm wondering how does facebook change the url when I switch between pictures in a album? There is no hash-tag, just a real url.

Example:
The current url: facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=XXXXXX1 and if I click next, the url changes to facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=XXXXXX2

Does anybody know how to realize this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

It pushes a new history state (an HTML5 thing) instead of using the hash key.

Comment: Can this work crossdomain? if yes then any site can pretend to be another site :( Look everywere.

Comment: @JamesM-SiteGen: No it does not work crossdomains, as stated in the link provided by  Matthew Brown: "The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL;"

Comment: It's supported from IE10 on, and all other reasonable browsers.

Answer (score 1):

My first hunch would be:

```
document.location = facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=XXXXXX2;
```

With some way of preventing the default reload page action.

Comment: There is no way to prevent a reload if you change the URL (except hash).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it was just a theory.

Comment: ReferenceError: facebook is not defined :) it is not a string :) And in this case should have "http:// at the start

Answer (score 1):

Summerizing all the answers,

we can say (I'm not a FB coder) that Facebook uses:

- the HTML5 `window.history.pushState / replaceState / popState` methods on browser that support these methods (I think one is Chrome). In this way Facebook **changes the real url** (not just the part after the `#` character).
- On other browsers, that do not support these new HTML5 methods (like IE6 / IE7 and IE8), Facebook simply changes the part of the url after the `#` character, by simply setting the the `window.location.hash` property.

Answer (score 0):

On my tests, it only changes the hash tag:

E.g. the real URL is:

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=x&set=z
```

and clicking next results in:

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=x&set=z#!/photo.php?fbid=y&set=z&pid=pid&id=id
```

The part after the hash is setup for [Google AJAX crawl](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).  But for the purpose of the browser, it's just a hash (fragment identifier).

Comment: Yea I have noticed it updates that hash which is really similar to the url so it is confusing.

Comment: @dan, you're right, it is doing something different on Firefox 4.  The hash isn't used and the address bar never changes, but if I keep a shell open, `window.location` updates.

Comment: The pushState function only works in FF.4 and chrome :) Although on facebook I get hash changes.